# How to access anaconda packages?

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, opensuse, netcdf

I'm on an OpenSUSE install.  A lot of the work seems to already be done. I know other users have been able to access the library.

I need to be able to `import netcdf4`, but when I try to run, this happens:

```
  File "run.py", line 2, in <module>
    from netCDF4 import Dataset
ImportError: No module named netCDF4
```

Running `sudo conda install netcdf4` produces a large output which ends with:

```
Hint: the following combinations of packages create a conflict with the
remaining packages:
  - numpy 1.7*
  - netcdf4
```

The directory `/user/local/anaconda/pkgs/libnetcdf-4.2.1.1-1` exists.

I can't share my whole `$PATH` but it contains

```
/user/local/anaconda/bin
```

`$PYTHONPATH` is

```
/user/local/anaconda/bin:/user/local/anaconda/lib:/user/local/anaconda/pkgs
```

Do I need something else in my `$PATH` or `$PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: One detail I'm not quite clear on is where is the actual file or set of files that python is looking for, when I type import netcdf4?  Or where should it be?  Assuming that you start with the starting point of /user/local/anaconda?

Answer (score 1):

Might be an issue with an older numpy version. Try this:

```
conda update numpy
```

and then

```
conda install netCDF4
```

Comment: I believe this is the fastest answer I've EVER had on stackoverflow and it's a Friday night.  You are awesome.  EDIT: Unfortunately, it wasn't sufficient on its own.  I was able to do both of those steps, but the problem remains.  I did log out and log back in so whatever changes were made should be up to date?  What should I have as my environment variables?

Comment: hmm, what is your numpy version now? not sure if it is an issue with your environment variables

Comment: 1.3.0?  And I'd be inclined to think that since others seem to have been able to use the netCDF4 libraries in the past, that the proper files are all on the system...So whatever the problem is, it is perhaps most likely that it's within my home directory.

Comment: your numpy version is very old, the latest is 1.10. Others might not be facing this problem since they have compatible numpy versions

Comment: So I've done a lot of exploring and discussing the system with a friend and...there is a LOT wrong with this system.  His colorful term was "bandaids to fix a brain tumor."  I've given up on doing it this way, and instead ended up using Canopy to set up a virtual environment in my own directory.